# splitting by dash in scala and selecting second one

Tags: scala, data-manipulation, apache-spark-mllib

We have a csv file having a column(name:Host) that has data like mb-**web**-scp-01, kl-**mem**-cpp-01 .

Having split by dash, I need to make a new column(name: Host2) having second one (web, mem from the above data)

```
import scala.io.Source._
```

Comment: `"mb-web-scp-01".split("-")(1)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to handle errors as options, you can do this (output from Ammonite REPL):

```
@ "mb-web-scp-01".split("-").drop(1).headOption
res1: Option[String] = Some(web)
```